# Keep android sof keyboard shown

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I added "Go" button in the soft keyboard and any time that i am pressing it keyboard is hiding. How to keep it shown? Using this code to show it does not work. Thanks

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited the answer for u, if u miss setSingleLine(true) the whole stuff will not work..I thought u have added,but u may not have been  Try this bro:

```
    et1.setHint("testing");
    et1.setImeActionLabel("Go", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
    et1.setSingleLine(true);


    et1.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO){


                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(et1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
                return true;
            }

            else
                return false;
        }
    } );
```

Comment: I guess u have forgot to do this while setting IME actions for ur edit text..
editText.setSingleLine(true)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your keyboard to be shown on the start of your activity you can add below line to AndroidManifest.xml inside your activity tag :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

and to resolve your 'GO' button problem you can use following code:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                          Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0); //to hide
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED); //to show
```

You can use this on any event appropriate to your task like `TextWatcher's` `onTextChanged` , editor listeners.

Comment: It is working too, but looks very annoying cause keyborad every time goes up and down.

Comment: Can you just post the sequence of operations step by step , how you are dealing with stuff...may be then help will be more accurate.

Comment: Thank you very much for help. The answer above works fine. I am checking in my app the value of edittext with the value from DB and showing it in textview.